# How to check an array of $curauth fields?

Tags: array

How do I check an array of $curauth user data? I need to check to see if one or more $curauth fields have data, and if so, print some html. This throws an array error:

```
    <?php if ( !empty( array ( $curauth->facebook, $curauth->linkedin, $curauth->twitter)))
{ echo 'echo me if any $curauth info exists for the fields in the array above'; } ?>
```

**Update - this works:**

```
<?php  if (!empty ($curauth->facebook) || ($curauth->linkedin) || ($curauth->twitter))
{ echo 'echo me if any $curauth info exists for the fields in the array above';  }  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php 
if ( !empty( array ( $curauth->facebook ) ) || 
     !empty ( array ( $curauth->linkedin ) ) || 
     !empty( array( $curauth->twitter ) ) )
{ 
    echo 'echo me if any $curauth info exists'; 
} 
?>
```

<sup>**Note:** This can be all on fewer lines, I've just put in additional line-breaks to make it all fit to avoid a horizontal scrollbar.</sup>

---

**Update**:
Reading up on [Author Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates) made me realise that once you've set the `$curauth` variable, e.g.

```
$curauth = (get_query_var('author_name')) ? get_user_by('slug', get_query_var('author_name')) : get_userdata(get_query_var('author'));
```

you should be able to use this instead:

```
<?php 
if ( !empty ( $curauth->facebook ) || 
     !empty ( $curauth->linkedin ) || 
     !empty ( $curauth->twitter ) )
{ 
    echo 'echo me if any $curauth info exists'; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I already call the $curauth variable. I wasn't formatting the array the right way. But the code can be simplified a little as noted in my update to my question.